# What are Catenary rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

A ring is catenary if it is Noetherian and for every pair of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{q}$, any maximal chain of prime ideals
$$
\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{p}_1 \subset \cdots \subset \mathfrak{p}_n = \mathfrak{q} 
$$
has the same length.

What types of structures are catenary rings suppose to capture? What are some examples and counterexamples?

Comment: In algebraic geometry, prime ideals correspond to "irreducible sub varieties".  Not sure how much geometry you have seen, but this basically means a sub variety that is not a finite union of other sub varieties.  Dimension in algebraic geometry is usually defined as the length of a maximal chain of prime ideals.  Being catenary says that this definition makes sense, and also has other nice and expected properties.

Comment: Geometrically, this makes sense. It seems like every subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^n$ or $\mathbb{P}^n$ should correspond to a catenary ring over some catenary base. Then, some base rings that I expect to be catenary are fields, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathcal{O}_K$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$, localizations of catenary rings along primes...

Comment: There is a famous example of a non catenary ring due to Nagata.  It's also neat because it's finitely generated over a catenary ring, which shows that the base is catenary but not universally catenary.  It's definitely worth learning if you're serious about commutative algebra

Comment: @Callus do you have a reference?

Comment: Nagata's book on local rings.  In the appendix I think.  There's also a sketch on the Wikipedia link.

Answer (score 1):

*Examples of catenary rings:*

An integral domain of (Krull) dimension $2$ is catenary, as is any  finitely generated algebra over a field. A quotient of a catenary ring is catenary.

An example of a non-catenary ring is given in *Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra*, ch. VIII, *Dimension*, §1, exercise 16 (it requires exercises 14 and 15).

Comment: I do not have access to Bourbaki.

Comment: Even in a university library?

Comment: @Bernard I know this is an old question, but I don't really think it's reasonable to assume people have access to a university library. That said, it's better to provide an inaccessible reference than no reference at all.